# Bad or no internet connection checker

Tags: java, android, connection

im trying to implement for my app offline mode. I found some codes on SO
First time i was using

```
public static boolean CheckConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;

    }
```

This function called every 1-3 seconds in service.
and this part work if we realy set off wifi or 3g/4g . But if we connected to wifi and wifi dont have access to internet  than this code also return (internet ok)

I found another way .. look like good .  BUT

```
 public boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            return (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but what about : if i will use this code every 1-2 seconds in service (i have service which checking internet connections ). 
Its bad or no ?  Can any answer. Regard Peter.

Answer (score 2):

Everything will be covered if you use this class:

```
    public class Connectivity {
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }


    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }


    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }


    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }


    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type== ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                    return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                    return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                    return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                    return false; // ~ 100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                    return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                    return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                    return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11
                    return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                    return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                    return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                    return false; // ~25 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                    return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
                // Unknown
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hm. nice class i willl check it

Comment: way is ok , but its still have a problem when we connected to wifi which not have internet access.

Comment: The 'isConnectionFast' function is wrong. Just because you're connected to wifi doesn't mean your connection is fast.

Answer (score 0):

check Internet Connection:

```
        private Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

        isInternetPresent =isConnectingToInternet() ;

        if(isInternetPresent){
            }else{}


       public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a simple `InetAddress`, like this:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This may draw less resources off your device.